# Universal Log Analyzer...!

Tags: logging, analyzer

Is there exist something like 'Universal Log Analyzer'?

I mean by Universal Log Anlyzer that it can analyze most kind of log files generated by Java/.Net/etc. written softwares.

My intention is not to use it for every kind of log files. I am actually looking for such software that only need to configure some part of Log Analyzer(e.g. provide some expression or pattern syntax) and based on that it can generate some analysis for me. I have googled much on this topic but not find much solution on it.

Need info on both Paid and Free Softwares.

Thanks,
Manish Patil.

Comment: you can try http://code.google.com/p/jlibs/wiki/GrepLog

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [log parser](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=890cd06b-abf8-4c25-91b2-f8d975cf8c07&displaylang=en). It is free tool from Microsoft, that allows parse and query almost all kinds of log. Here is description from official site:

> Log parser is a powerful, versatile tool that provides universal query access to text-based data such as log files, XML files and CSV files, as well as key data sources on the Windows® operating system such as the Event Log, the Registry, the file system, and Active Directory®. You tell Log Parser what information you need and how you want it processed. The results of your query can be custom-formatted in text based output, or they can be persisted to more specialty targets like SQL, SYSLOG, or a chart.
>
> Most software is designed to accomplish a limited number of specific tasks. Log Parser is different... the number of ways it can be used is limited only by the needs and imagination of the user. The world is your database with Log Parser.

Comment: Thinx for info. i will have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

*There ain't no such thing as a free lunch.*

Many universal log analyzers exist. But you have to define configuration files yourself for handling your own log files.

Examples: grep, awk, perl, python, ...

Comment: Thats what I want..... Defining configuration files is OK. But everytime for new tool writing new log analyzer in not good idea.